# Biexponential Model and Gompertz Model

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, nonlinear

Is there any one can give me some information about Biexponential and Gompertz Models ???
the models are

y_i=ϕ_1  exp⁡[-exp⁡(ϕ_2 )x]+ϕ_3  exp⁡[-exp⁡(ϕ_4 )x]

y_i=ϕ_1  exp⁡〖(ϕ_2 x^(ϕ_3 ))〗
i need information about them like definition and properties 
I really need some help because i don't know anything about these two models.
please can someone give some names of popular books or thesis about this subject
Thanks.

Comment: This is too broad. Please edit your post to ask a specific question

Comment: I will really appreciate if you can give some names of popular books or thesis about this subject, Glen_b

Comment: If you want to edit your question to ask for references, you could try that

Comment: See Generalized Linear Models second edition by Myers, Montgomery,Vining and Robinson. Mary A. Marion